# MySQL error code 1146 in MySQL Workbench action output

Tags: sql, mysql-error-1146

I have just started learning SQL. When I wrote this code

```
create database tutorial_1;
use tutorial_1;
create table tutorial
(
id int primary key,
name varchar(40),
duration decimal(4,2),
date date
);
insert into tutorial(id, name, duration, date)
values(1, 'c', 23.12, '2014-02-10');
insert into tutorial
values(2, 'python', 12.45, '2014-02-11');
insert into tutorial
values(3, 'sql', 34.17, '2014-02-14');

create database tutorial_2;
use tutorial_2;
create table tutorial_info
(
tutorial_id int primary key,
views int(40),
likes int(40),
dislikes int(40),
shares int(40)
);
insert into tutorial_info(tutorial_id, views, likes, dislikes, shares)
values (1, 23411, 124, 12, 19);
insert into tutorial_info(tutorial_id, views, likes, dislikes, shares)
values (2, 29019, 920, 100, 234);
insert into tutorial_info
values (3, 9019, 129, 23, 8);
insert into tutorial_info

SELECT t.id, t.name,
ti.views, ti.likes, ti.dislikes, ti.shares
FROM tutorial AS t
JOIN tutorial_info AS ti
ON t.id=ti.tutorial_id;
```

on SQL file, action output shows:

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'tutorial_2.tutorial' doesn't exist   0.000 sec

but when I checked the table on SCHEMAS, I found that table. What do I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two separate databases: `tutorial_1` and `tutorial_2`.

Then, you switch to the `tutorial_2` database. After that, you are selecting a join between `tutorial` and `tutorial_info`. `tutorial` is in the `tutorial_1` database, while `tutorial_info` is in `tutorial_2` database. Since you are in `tutorial_2` database, MySQL tries to load records from the `tutorial` table, which does not exist in the `tutorial_2` database, since it was created into the `tutorial_1` database.

EDIT:
I have conducted a few experiments and I believe you can do a cross-database join like this:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name,
ti.views, ti.likes, ti.dislikes, ti.shares
FROM tutorial_1.tutorial AS t
JOIN tutorial_info AS ti
ON t.id=ti.tutorial_id;
```

Comment: @pharask, you might consider accepting the answer, so people in the future will know the solution.

Comment: I wrote the code you suggested and It worked but It's working if I am inside tutorial_2 database only (   i.e   use tutorial_2 ; ). It's not working if I am inside tutorial_1 database.....is there any reason?

Comment: Yes, the reason is the same. In tutorial_1 you cannot find the tutorial_info table. Use tutorial_2.tutorial_info instead in your select.

Comment: @pharask: please accept one of the answers you have been provided with (there are two, and you may accept either one, since they both appear to be correct). "Accepting an answer" means clicking the tick symbol to the left of it, so that it is marked as useful. It is how we thank helpful people here.

Comment: @pharask: let me know if you wish to accept one of these answers, and I'll undownvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

`tutorial` is a table of database `tutorial_1`, while you are working in the scope of database `tutorial2` (after `use tutorial_2`). So you should write:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name,
ti.views, ti.likes, ti.dislikes, ti.shares
FROM tutorial_1.tutorial AS t
JOIN tutorial_info AS ti
ON t.id=ti.tutorial_id;
```

In general you should work only a single database.

Comment: Glad to have helped! And if you are satisfied with the answer (and only in this case), please don't forget to accept it, thanks.

Comment: Renzo, there are perfectly valid cases to work with multiple databases. For instance, you might host multiple projects on the same server. You might want to separate their databases. For example, you might have a company, which needs a database for accounting and another database for business plans. You might have different people working on those databases. I can imagine a cron job which analyzes some data regarding both databases.

Comment: @LajosArpad, of course there are many cases in which one could work concurrently with several databases, but the OP is declaring himself: "I have just started learning SQL", and my suggestion was given for these reason. Note, in addition, that in systems like PostgreSQL it not easy to work on different databases (you can, but you see them as external objects), while you can work on different schemas of the same database. So, when learning SQL, I think is better to start with a single database at time.

Comment: I agree with your statement that "when learning SQL, I think is better to start with a single database at time.", but I consider your other statement of "In general you should work only a single database." misleading, especially for beginners. Also, the op uses MySQL, as we can clearly see from the tags of the question, so your observation about PostgreSQL is off-topic in this case. Finally, the op can write cross-database queries, as shown in my answer, which is the solution to the actual problem.